# C# Passing Dynamic Object To Form When Using Internal?

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying pass a dynamic object from Main to Form via an internal modifier.  In relation to making two sets of variables within a property class in order to revert the form's elements back to default if the user chooses cancel.

Here is a representation of my current code which is yielding an error:

> 'MYFORM_FORM' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Code: Slimmed down.  C# version: 4.0.30319.42000  (As this is an inline container, I have no control over namespace and updates)

```
public class Settings {
     
     public string MYPathFile_M { get; set; }
     
     public Settings Clone() {
          return new Settings() { MYPathFile_M = this.MYPathFile_M };
     }
}

public class MYline {

     public static Settings defaultSettings = null;

     [STAThread]
     public void main() {
          defaultSettings = new Settings { MYPathFile_M = "some value" };
          Application.Run(new MYFORM_FORM(defaultSettings.Clone(), MY)); // MY = Dynamic Object
     }
}

public class MYFORM_FORM : Form {
     public string result = null;
     private Settings settings = null;
     private BindingSource settingsSource = null;

     // I have to pass the dynamic object here in order for the code below to do various things with that object.
     public MYFORM_FORM(dynamic MY)
     {
          this.ClientSize = new Size(1452, 577);
          this.Font = new Font("Arial", 12F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
          this.Margin = new Padding(2, 4, 2, 4);
          this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
          this.MaximizeBox = false;
          this.MinimizeBox = false;
          this.ControlBox = false;
          this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
          this.MinimumSize = new Size(this.Width, this.Height);
          this.MaximumSize = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
          int FontSize = 12;
          int ControlSpacing = 15;
          this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler((sender, e) => MYFORM_FORM_FormClosing(sender, e, MY));
          this.Load += new System.EventHandler((sender, e) => MYFORM_FORM_Load(sender, e, MY));
          this.Name = "MYFORM_FORM";
          this.Text = "Settings";

          RichTextBox MYBox = new RichTextBox();
          MYBox.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
          MYBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
          MYBox.Location = new Point(12, 68);
          MYBox.Name = "MyBox";
          MYBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Vertical;
          MYBox.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
          MYBox.Size = new Size(938, 56);
          MYBox.TabIndex = 0;
          MYBox.TabStop = false;
          this.Controls.Add(MYBox);
          MYBox.BringToFront();   

          Button Cancel_Button = new Button();
          Cancel_Button.AutoEllipsis = true;
          Cancel_Button.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
          Cancel_Button.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
          Cancel_Button.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
          Cancel_Button.Location = new Point(1035, 517);
          Cancel_Button.Name = "Cancel_Button";
          Cancel_Button.Text = "CANCEL";
          Cancel_Button.Size = new Size(200, 48);
          Cancel_Button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;  
          Cancel_Button.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => Cancel_Button_Clicked(sender, e, MY)); 
          this.Controls.Add(Cancel_Button);

     Functions.ShowForm(this); 

     }

     internal MYFORM_FORM(Settings initialSettings, dynamic MY) : this() {
          settings = initialSettings;
          if (settings != null) {
           settingsSource = new BindingSource(settings, null);
               InitializeSettingsBindings();
          }
     }

     private void InitializeSettingsBindings() {
          MYBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", settingsSource, "MYPathFile_M", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
     }

     private void Cancel_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e, dynamic MY) {
          settings = MY.Settings.defaultSettings.Clone();
      if (settingsSource != null) settingsSource.DataSource = settings;
          Close();
     }
}

public class Functions() {
     public static void ShowForm(Form f) {
          IntPtr myHandle = f.Handle;
      SetForegroundWindow(myHandle.ToInt32());
     }

     [DllImport("User32.dll")]
     public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);
}
```

Tried swapping in/out dynamic object in main form constructor but errors either way.  either 0 arguments not allowed, of dynamic object isn't passed and subsequent code kicks out errors due to that.

Objective is when user hits the cancel button, it will reload form with original(default) values and populate back into the form.